# Evento mouseover e evento onclick para um mesmo conjunto de elementos

Tags: click, eventos-do-mouse

Galera, como posso fazer para que meu mouseover e click, funcione para um conjunto de elementos, no meu caso um img e duas labels:

Teste de Imagem

```
<style>
    .imgImportacao{
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 700px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .mudarmouse{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .container{
        position: relative;
    }

    .texto1{
        position:absolute;
        font-size: 40px;
        left: 755px;
        top:35px;
        color: white;
    }

    .texto2{
        position:absolute;
        font-size: 20px;
        left: 722px;
        top:95px;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
```

14
        Contribuintes

```
    <script>


            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#testeimg").click(function(){

                alert("teste");

                }); 
            });


    </script>
```

Comment: trabalhe com classes, e adicione a mesma classe para os elementros que deseja que tenha o mesmo evento...